# Foreman - replacing repo with local mirrors

Tags: ruby, erb, theforeman

We use foreman (v1.14.1) for provisioning and we have a working CentOS 7 installation media for the base OS. 
When installing it does install the default repos in /etc/yum.repos.d with online mirrors but I want to replace this with our local mirrors.

I ran accross [this workflow (from 2012)](http://sysadminpy.com/sysadmin/2012/03/18/managing-yum-repository-list-with-the-foreman/)
It uses the following snippet to iterate over all the media of the current host os and set write out a repo definition.

```
<% @host.os.media.each do |media| -%>
[<%= media.name.downcase.strip.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '') %>]
name=<%= media.name %>
baseurl=<%= @host.os.medium_uri @host, media.path %>
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
<% end -%>
```

I have set several Installation media for this OS, each one of them having a specific repo URI (Base, Updates, Plus, Extras...).

The snippet is called in the %post install section of the kickstart but when I want to build the host I get the following error:

```
Failure parsing Kickstart default: The snippet 'FF_repos' threw an error: 
undefined method 'media' for Operatingsystem::Jail (Redhat).
```

I understand that "@host.os.media.each" is not correct for iterating over the different medias, but how could I do it ?
Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get this to work so I have simply changed my snippet "FF_repos" to directly bake the repos definition into corresponding repo files on disk.

I added the following in the %post section then to remove default repos and leave our.

```
rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/*
<%= snippet("FF_repos") %>
```